# How to get information from a sheet in a mail that will be automatically send

Tags: javascript, arrays, email

I am not a developper but I working on a way to send automatic mails of information coming for a googlesheet.

here is what I want to do :

1/ get the mail adress of the ligne in the sheet 1

2/ on the sheet 2, we looking for the line where we have this adress

3/ from the sheet 2, construct an array which contain all the information for the line where we find the mail adress

4/ automatically send the mail to me which contain all the information that are in the array we created

I think that I only have a problem in getting the data in the array because I did a test by sending a "Hello world" mail, and it works.

The error is : "ReferenceError: infoRandonneur is not defined (line 8)"
I don't know it doesn't find "infoRandonneur" ...

Here is my 3 function :

```
function MailProduit(){
  
  var feuille1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var data_range1 = feuille1.getDataRange();
  var dernier_rang1 = data_range1.getLastRow();
  
  for(var ligne=2; ligne<=dernier_rang1;ligne++){
    var isFormulaireOk=feuille1.getRange(ligne,1).getValue();
    if(isFormulaireOk == "Formulaire OK"){
      
      var mail1 = feuille1.getRange(ligne,13).getValue();
      var nom1 = feuille1.getRange(ligne,4).getValue();
      var prenom1 = feuille1.getRange(ligne,5).getValue();
      envoyerMailProduit(nom1,prenom1,mail1,ligne);
      feuille1.getRange(ligne,1).setValue("Mail produit envoyé");
    }
  
  }
}  

function envoyerMailProduit(nom,prenom,mail,ligne){
  
  var mailRandonneur = mail;
  var ligneProduit = ligne;
  
  var info = recupererInfoCommande(mailRandonneur,ligneProduit);
  
  var modele = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ProduitCommande');
  var message = modele.evaluate().getContent();
  var adressemail = "baptistelautrette@hotmail.fr";
  
  modele.infoRandonneur = info; 
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: adressemail,
    subject: "Produits à commander pour un randonneur",
    htmlBody: message
  });
  
}

function recupererInfoCommande(mailRandonneur,ligneRandonneur)
{
  var mailVerif=mailRandonneur; 
  var ligneVerif = ligneRandonneur; 
  var feuille2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 2');
  var data_range2 = feuille2.getDataRange();
  var dernier_rang2 = data_range2.getLastRow();
  var valeurs = feuille2.getRange(ligneVerif,6,ligneVerif,26).getValues();

  
  var enregistrement = valeurs[0];
  var adressemail = "baptistelautrette@hotmail.fr";
  
  for(var ligne=2; ligne<=dernier_rang2;ligne++){
    var mailRecherche = feuille2.getRange(ligne,2).getValue();
    if (mailVerif == mailRecherche){
      var infoRandonneur = 
      {
        sacH:enregistrement[0],
        sockH:enregistrement[1],
        tailleSockH: enregistrement[2],
        pantalonH:enregistrement[3],
        taillePantalonH:enregistrement[4],
        ponchoH:enregistrement[5],
        taillePonchoH:enregistrement[6],
        tshirtH:enregistrement[7],
        tailleTshirtH:enregistrement[8],
        polaireH:enregistrement[9],
        taillePolaireH:enregistrement[10],
        casquetteH:enregistrement[11],
        batonH:enregistrement[12],
        sacF:enregistrement[13],
        sockF:enregistrement[14],
        tailleSockF: enregistrement[15],
        pantalonF:enregistrement[16],
        taillePantalonF:enregistrement[17],
        ponchoF:enregistrement[18],
        taillePonchoF:enregistrement[19],
        tshirtF:enregistrement[20],
        tailleTshirtF:enregistrement[21],
        polaireF:enregistrement[22],
        taillePolaireF:enregistrement[23],
        casquetteF:enregistrement[24],
        batonF:enregistrement[25]
      };
      
      return infoRandonneur;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my mail that I want to send :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <p> Hello World </p>
  <p> <?= infoRandonneur.sacF ?> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

For execution, I only launch MailProduit() that has to find if the situation of the hiker ('form OK' for example), then if it's ok, that launch envoyerMailProduit(), that looks on the other sheet to find the ligne where we find the adress of this hiker, get all the data from the line, and send the mail "ProduitCommande".

So, when I don't put infoRandonneur.sacF in the mail, it works, but like that it doesn't ...

If someone could help me, it would be great.

Thanks,
Baptiste L.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 declaration of functions but I don't see the execution order of them. Can you please update the question with it? In order to know in which line you get the error. Or is it in the email?

You say you're not a developer so maybe you don't know this but, declaring a function does not make it run, you have to CALL a function in order to get it executed.

For example:

```
function hello_world() {
  document.write("Hello world! - I am just plain text");
} // This declares the function

hello_world(); // This calls the function declared previously
```

EDIT:

So this is not the problem. Try to make some debugging of your code by writing this in a line where the variable should have a value:

```
document.write("Variable name: " + variable_name); // The text before the actual variable name will help you to not get lost in the output.

// An example with your code:
var info = recupererInfoCommande(mailRandonneur,ligneProduit);
document.write("Info variable: " + info); // This will output the info value at that line.
```

I suggest you check the variables are arriving to your functions as they are supposed.

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks, 

But I execute function MailProduit(), with in the function envoyerMailProduit() is executed, with in the function recupererInfoCommande() is executed too.

So I thought that I only had to execute MailProduit(), that's right ? 

Thanks

Comment: Yes. My bad, you are calling functions inside the MailProduit(), so that's ok. First of all, look if the variables you are sending to the function recupererInfoCommande() are arriving correctly (mailRandonneur,ligneRandonneur) (with the print() command). Also, check if the variable info in  envoyerMailProduit() has some value after the line it is created. You can see the value of a variable by writing print("Variable name: " + variable_name); It will print it in the output along the errors. I will edit my answer later with a couple of examples.

Comment: Use document.write() instead of print(). Excuse me, don't know why I said print in the first place.

Comment: Also, check this link about arrays in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array